# List of positive integers NOT divisible by smallest q prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I can get a list of positive integers less than a given positive integer, $N$, divisible by two primes, let's say $3$ and $5$. But if I increase the prime count higher and higher it gets messy.

> Is there any way to get the list of integers from the set  $\{2...N\}$ being not divisible by the primes $\{2, 3, 5, 7, ..., q^{th} prime\}$.

For example for $N=20$ and $q=3$, I would get the list of positive integers not divisible by 2,3,5. i.e. the set $\{1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19\}$. Well things get hairy when the prime list gets bigger. Hope there are some easy solution to this which I missed.

EDIT:
Currently I'm using a wheel factor factorization code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553925/), but it becomes unwieldy very soon and for when the number N becomes in the range of 10^10 nor higher it starts crawling. So I'm looking for something faster/memory efficient to get the numbers. So is it possible or not?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it too easy a problem? Do I need to rewrite the problem statement? ?

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes?

Comment: @gammatester first of all I'm using it in a python code. Currently I'm using a wheel-30 factor factorization code, but it becomes unwieldy very soon and for when the number N becomes in the range of 10^10 nor higher it starts crawling. So I'm looking for something faster/memory efficient  to get the numbers. So is it possible or not?

Comment: I'm following this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553925/

Comment: When you say *start crawling* I do not know what you can expect from Python. One of the fastest sieves available http://primesieve.org/ claims to sieve up to $10^{10}$ in  0.57 s.
But it contains a link to https://github.com/hickford/primesieve-python

Comment: Well I had already tried to use primesieve, but somehow it fails to get to a working install. Had opened a issue in that repo. Anyway looks like no other way out of this.